# Ask help for cargo test for no_std

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

In my project, I used `#![no_main]`，and have the following in my `Cargo.toml`

```toml
[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

`cargo build` works, but `cargo test` fails with my settings.

```
error: language item required, but not found: `eh_personality`
  |
  = note: this can occur when a binary crate with `#![no_std]` is compiled for a target where `eh_personality` is defined in the standard library
  = help: you may be able to compile for a target that doesn't need `eh_personality`, specify a target with `--target` or in `.cargo/config`
```

I looked for infos about "panic-strategy", but I don't know how to use it.